# PyQt Windows doesn't appear

Tags: python, pyqt5

[My Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQeYx.png)

Can someone tell me why my PyQt Windows doesn't appear after I start the Programm? (Its Converter from PyQt Designer)

When I try ui.show() instead of Dialog.show() it says: Unresolved attribute reference 'show' for class 'Ui_Dialog'

Comment: try ui.show() instead of Dialog.show()

Comment: Never post images of your code. Instead copy-paste the code in your question.

Comment: You forgot to add `sys.exit (app.exec_ ())` at the very end
and what @f.wue wrote you must remember forever.

Comment: When I try ui.show() instead of Dialog.show() it says: Unresolved attribute reference 'show' for class 'Ui_Dialog'

Answer (score 0):

> When I try ui.show() instead of Dialog.show() it says: Unresolved attribute reference 'show' for class 'Ui_Dialog'

The `ui` variable just holds the UI data, it isn't a Qt object.

```
import sys
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog() # Lowercase for objects, dialog
ui = Ui_Dialog
ui.setupUI(Dialog)

# At this point dialog is your actual dialog object
# and ui is still just UI data.
dialog.show()  # Show your dialog.
```

Calling `.show()` is non-blocking, it just an instruction. However, to make Qt execute that instruction you need to start up the Qt event loop (this is what handles putting your windows on the screen and taking user input).

```
# Call app.exec_() to start the Qt event loop.
app.exec_()
```

Note that dialog boxes also have their *own* `.exec_()` which can be used to issue a blocking dialog (that prevents interaction with the parent app). If you call `dialog.exec_()` instead you should still see your dialog box. However, your app won't be able to do anything else, because as soon as you close the dialog box the event loop will end.